# Database design, I'm confused how my relationships should look and if I should have composite keys in any of those tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

For each movie there should be a possibility to store list of actors and creators. The list with actors should contain name, surname, and the name of the character in the movie. The creators list should contain name, surname, phone number, email, and the job title (e.g. director, actor). The movie can have more that one director.

The same person can be on actors list and creators list. The actor can play more than one role. The creator can have more than one function.

I came up with something but I'm not very confident about it,if anyone could guide me through this your help would really be appreciated. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that crosses my mind seeing your design is a problem around Actor and Creator who could, or not, be the same person.

I would advise you to start with a Person Table with all the common characteristics of a person : name, surname, phone_number, email.

Then, Your tables Actor, Creator, Director, would have a non nullable foreign key pointing to that table Person. Because every Actor, Creator, etc IS before all a Person.

I think it would go a long way to solve your problems...

Comment: ohh okay,so to differentiate between all of them do I have to have a composite key in persons table making person_id and job_title as primary keys?

Comment: Why do you want to use a composite key ? What is your use case ? When you are querying your db, you can check if a given person is an actor , you can make a join query...

Answer (score 0):

You must have one an only one entity that have all the attributes of a person. Actor, Director... are persons that can act sometime as actor sometime as director. As an example Clint Estwood.

I give this MCD as an exercices for my students (this is a french one, but I think you can easyli read it :
https://www.developpez.net/forums/attachments/p599148d1622794816/general-developpement/alm/modelisation/schema/dependance-fonctionnelle-aide/mcd-film-1.1.jpg/